# In JDBC, what should I do if a Connection fails to rollback?

Tags: java, jdbc

The Java documentation of the interface java.sql.Connection says this about the close() method: "It is strongly recommended that an application explicitly commits or rolls back an active transaction prior to calling the close method. If the close method is called and there is an active transaction, the results are implementation-defined."

This creates a subtle but serious problem: If I call the rollback() method of a Connection but this method fails (for example, a timeout occurs), then can I call the close() method of this Connection? Is it possible that there is still an active transaction when I call the close() method, and so the results are implementation-defined, and so the transaction may be committed?

I can choose to not call the close() method if the rollback() fails, but this may make the JDBC resources not released. Furthermore, maybe eventually the close() method will be called (maybe when the Connection object is garbage-collected). If this is the case, then this approach will not help.

So, what should I do when the rollback() method of a Connection fails? If the rollback() method fails, can I still call the close() method of this Connection?

Comment: In general, if a rollback failed, you either did something wrong (e.g. calling commit in auto-commit, or when you're in a distributed transaction, or the connection is closed), or things are so broken (e.g. connection issues, or mismatch in state between driver and server), that closing the connection is probably the only sane action left. In such situation, it is likely that the database server will rollback after you close the connection.

Answer (score 6):

> If I call the `rollback()` method of a `Connection` but this method fails (for example, a timeout occurs), then can I call the `close()` method of this `Connection`?

According to the JDBC specification, `SQLTransactionRollbackException` is a Transient `SQLException`.

> A Transient `SQLException` will be thrown in situations where a previously failed operation might be able to succeed when the operation is retried without any intervention by application-level functionality. After a Transient `SQLException` other than `SQLTransientConnectionException` occurs, the application can assume that the connection is still valid.

So, if the `rollback()` failed with an `SQLTransactionRollbackException`, you should be able to `close()` the connection, or retry the `rollback()`.  (If you called `close()`, after calling `rollback()` it would be *perverse* for the driver to commit the transaction.)

However, if the `rollback()` failed with a `SQLTransientConnectionException` the connection will be invalid.  Calling `close()` could fail ... or it *might* commit the transaction<sup>1</sup>.  The cautious approach is to just abandon the `Connection`, and trust that the database will rollback the transaction automatically.  Alternatively, if you can figure out (from your driver's documentation, etc) that a `close()` *won't* commit a transaction, then call `close()`.

In the latter case, I think we should assume that when the JDBC driver detected that the connection has been lost it would release the `Socket` and other resources, as far as possible.  A `Socket` whose network connection has been broken cannot be "reopened" so there is no point hanging on to it.

If we didn't call `close()` and just forgot about the `Connection` (after a rollback failure), the resource leak probably doesn't matter since:

- database connection failures should be a rare occurrence,
- the Java GC should eventually finalize the `Connection` and release the associated `Socket` etcetera.

---

<sup>1 - In theory.  The JDBC Javadocs say that it is unspecified what happens if you `close()` a connection with an active transaction.  But it would be worth checking the documentation for the specific drivers that you are using.</sup>

Comment: So, the better way is to leave the Connection (not call its close() method) if the rollback fails, is it? But, if I don't call close() of the Connection, will this method be called later, when this Connection object is garbage-collected?

Comment: If you don't *know* that the specific driver driver wou are using will spontaneously commit transactions on `close()` then the *safest* thing is to drop the connection.  It will be garbage collected at some time in the future.  You don't know when.

Comment: @StephenC Just relying on the GC doesn't necessarily do the trick. A driver could attempt a clean close in a finalizer, and thus still try to commit in that case. However, I think your advice to just lose the connection is not a good idea: JDBC connections should be opened with try-with-resources to avoid resource leaks. Following this advice makes it far more likely to introduce resource leaks in applications.

Comment: Hmmm ... maybe need to do some research on what actual JDBC drivers do, as distinct from what the spec says they might do.

Comment: JDBC seems bad at this point. It does not make sense to allow a driver to commit the transaction when the transaction is active and the close method of the Connection object is called. In such a case, the transaction should always be cancelled (rolled back).